# How to start application with DooPHP?

Tags: php, frameworks, doophp

I am starting new application with DooPHP framework, but I don't have any idea, and not getting any clear documentation.
So I'm a little bit confused. How to start?
Is there any guide how to create model and controller and how to run?

Comment: Do you think its a good idea to start using a framework that has poor documentation?

Comment: i know, it's not good idea... .but my client's requirement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several tutorials of dooPHP:

Create a simple To Do List in DooPHP: http://learn.doophp.com/2009/09/create-a-simple-to-do-list-in-doophp-part-2/

Urls: 
http://learn.doophp.com/2009/09/

learn.doophp.com/2009/10/

learn.doophp.com/2009/11/

Upload and Resize Pictures with DooGdImage:
learn.doophp.com/2010/01

Handling sessions without Apache sessions:
learn.doophp.com/2010/09

Upload and Resize Pictures with DooGdImage:
learn.doophp.com/2010/01/

Answer (score 0):

I searched for 5 minutes and found this guide:

http://doophp.com/doc/guide/basic/model

There's how Models and Controllers are implemented and what parent classes they should inherit.

After creating a test controller and model, run it through the framework's URI schema: http://doophp.com/doc/guide/basic/routes

Here's the documentation root: http://doophp.com/doc

Comment: ya, i have found it.. .but it's not enough for building new application.. .i want documentation like codeigniter.